# Contar registros de 4 tablas

Tags: mysql, mysqli

No logro hacer esta query en `mySQL`.

Tengo 4 tablas.

1. Tabla principal socios cuyo campos son id, id_association, num_parter
2. Tabla tutores, cuyos registros son id, id_partner
3. Tabla children, cuyos registros son id, id_partner

Todas las tablas estan unidad por una clave foranea llamada `id_partner`

Necesito tener los campos de la tabla partner y cuantos tutores pertenece a cada socio, y cuantos children pertenece a cada socio

A ver si me podeis ayudar, gracias.

[image: Tabla Socios]

[image: Tabla tutores]

[image: Tabla Children]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  s.id, 
    s.id_association, 
    s.num_parther, 
    ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT t.id),0) AS cant_tutores, 
    ISNULL(COUNT(DISTINCT c.id),0) AS cant_children
    FROM socios AS s 
    LEFT JOIN tutores t 
        ON s.id = t.id_parther 
    LEFT JOIN children c
        ON s.id = c.id_parther 
    GROUP BY s.id, 
        s.id_association, 
        s.num_parther
```

- Con `LEFT JOIN` relacionamos las tablas hijas a `socios` sin invalidar aquellos socios que no tengan filas en estas.
- Contamos en cada caso, los distintos `id` existentes en cada hija
- Agrupamos por los datos de `socios` que queremos mostrar.

Comment: Perfecto!, muchisimas gracias!, resuelta la query.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con la siguiente consulta que te devuelve el número de tutores que tiene cada socio y realiza los cambios necesarios para devolver el número de niños.

```
SELECT s.id, s.id_association, s.num_parther, COUNT(*) AS num_tutores 
FROM socios AS s JOIN tutores AS t ON s.id = t.id_parther 
GROUP BY s.id, s.id_association, s.num_parther;
```